# Charts.js readable date formats and different background color if line below above zero

Tags: javascript, chart.js

i am trying since one day to find out how to set up everything to make the chart draw the way i need and i feel it takes to much time and i dont make any goals.

i know charts.js is normaly not difficult to use, but only as long as everythings works fine like the exampels you find, otherwise it become difficult if you are not a charts.js profi.

I have already put something into the chart which draw the background color in different colors if the line is negativ or positive and then i did want to try change the date values to make them look better but i dont get it.

please take a look at the following jsfiddle JSFidleuser12/o3c7d0h5/15/ and picture, it does explain all problems and thank you for any help
[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bMcAG.png)

Comment: I think you should use time or timeseries X axis in order to use the date formatting out of the box. you need to use chartjs-adapter and a date library (https://github.com/chartjs/awesome#adapters) https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/time.html

Comment: i have update my jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/JSFidleuser12/o3c7d0h5/26/  the problem for date formats i have slove some way, but i dont know currently how to make the red background not showing under the blue bachground, it shoul stop at zero line